# The dialog will disappear when I set a breakpoint in the debugger of chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z9kyt-JPk5f4s78h_Q5HzpsLkx84KTg6/view

In this video, I activate a calendar dialog and then a "+" is clicked by me. This action will generate a new dialog above the one of the calendar.

However, when I set a breakpoint for the function of generating the second dialog, the calendar dialog will disappear when the program stop in the breakpoint and then I click "step over" in the debugger.

Can someone explain the reason why? btw, this would not happen in firefox's debugger~

thx a lot

Comment: Your google drive file is not accessible to anyone with a link.

Comment: I had changed the google drive the shared link, thx for your remind~

Comment: Does the dialog have code that closes itself when the widow loses focus?

Comment: nope and this condition would not happen on firefox. it's only for chrome